# Invalid object passed in, member name expected

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert json string to Dictionary using JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(line) object.

Now this code work perfectly on my Windows 8 Machine, On my Testing Server Windows 2008 Enterprise R2 Service Pack 2 but its not working on Windows 2008 Standard R2 Service Pack 1.

Here is the snapshot of my code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer objScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> dictJson = null; 
dictJson = (Dictionary<string, object>)objScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(line);
```

Invalid object passed in, member name expected. (729): Below is the json string which is valid when i validated the json string.

```
{ "Action" : "ValidateDistributionGrid",
  "Data" : { "CompanyId" : "iqi",
      "CurrencySignatureOfInvoice" : "",
      "CurrentInvoiceDocType" : "Journal Entry",
      "GenericGridCollection" : [ { "ControlName" : "Distribution",
            "ValueCollection" : [ { "" : "",
                  "acccode" : "199871",
                  "acccodedescr" : "Account Not in Archimedes",
                  "amount" : "123.00",
                  "assetno" : "Affinity Express Philippines Inc.",
                  "branchno" : "Yes",
                  "category" : "Cost Center not in  Archimedes.",
                  "comments" : "ffd",
                  "companyid" : "",
                  "costcenter" : "1090",
                  "incident" : "",
                  "itemdesc" : "ZTest",
                  "lno" : ""
                },
                { "" : "",
                  "acccode" : "",
                  "acccodedescr" : "",
                  "amount" : "123.00",
                  "assetno" : "",
                  "branchno" : "",
                  "category" : "",
                  "comments" : "",
                  "companyid" : "",
                  "costcenter" : "",
                  "incident" : "",
                  "itemdesc" : "Distribution Total",
                  "lno" : ""
                },
                { "" : "",
                  "acccode" : "",
                  "acccodedescr" : "",
                  "amount" : "",
                  "assetno" : "Acclaim (Legacy) Energy SolutionsAffinity Express Philippines Inc.AG Counselors CorporationAlveo Land CorpAmicassa Process Solutions, Inc.ASG Group LimitedAvida Land, CorporationAyala Automotive Holdings CorpAyala CorporationAyala Land, Inc.Ayala Multi-Purpose CooperativeAyala Property Management CorpAyala System Technology, Inc.Bank of Philippine IslandsBillabongBloom EnergyCalgon CarbonCalifornia Pizza KitchenCalifornia United BankCambridge Major Laboratories, Inc.CapitaMallsCebu Holdings, Inc.ConergyCorel CorporationCrohn's & Colitis Foundation of AmericaDream CatchDVS Intele StreamEvolution Hospitality, LLCExtreme NetworksF. MclintocksGlobe Telecom, Inc.GoodwineGrill ConceptsHaas TCM, Inc.Haven Realty CapitalHealth Trust of AmericaInnovative Dining GroupIntegra Business Processing SolutionsIntegrated Microelectronics, Inc.Integrated Microelectronics, Inc.InterDent Service CorporationJamba Juice (Whirl Colorado)JM Smucker Co.Khronos, LLCLiveit Investment Ltd.Makati Development CorporationManila Water CorporationName Not Found1New Horizon Learning CenterOracle (Philippines) CorporationPSi Technologies, Inc.QuiznosRaben MediaRopes & GrayRosa MexicanoRustan Coffee, Inc.Sage Parts Plus, Inc.SBESILKROADSizzler USA Restaurant, IncSpectrum Pharmaceuticals, Inc.Stone & Pewter AccentsSunburst FarmsSupply Chain Consulting Inc.Sweetener ProductsSymetraTelus International Philippines, Inc.The Bank of Tokyo-Mitsubishi UFJ, Ltd.The Four Seasons Hotel ChicagoThe Four Seasons Hotel HoustonThe OrchardThe Philippine American Life and GeneralThe Ritz Carlton Hotel ChicagoTime OutTWB Company, LLCUnited Capital Financials PartnersVeecoVeggie Grill",
                  "branchno" : "YesNo",
                  "category" : "",
                  "comments" : "",
                  "companyid" : "",
                  "costcenter" : "",
                  "incident" : "",
                  "itemdesc" : "",
                  "lno" : ""
                }
              ]
          },
          { "ControlName" : "SpecialInstructions",
            "ValueCollection" : [ { "comment" : "Please scan invoice to client Archimedes instance then return item to IQB Finance.",
                  "companyid" : "iqi",
                  "resolutiondate" : "2/10/2014 4:37:35 PM",
                  "rno" : "1",
                  "si_code" : "10",
                  "userid" : "ajay vishwakarma",
                  "username" : "ajay"
                },
                { "comment" : "",
                  "companyid" : "",
                  "resolutiondate" : "",
                  "rno" : "",
                  "si_code" : "",
                  "userid" : "",
                  "username" : ""
                }
              ]
          }
        ],
      "ImageId" : "11240088",
      "IncidentNumber" : "10357",
      "InvoiceActualAmount" : "343.0000",
      "NextApproverID" : "cden.iqi",
      "OriginalApprovalEmail" : "",
      "PONumber" : "344334",
      "PathName" : "",
      "RowNo" : "2",
      "SortString" : "",
      "Status" : "E",
      "UserApprovalLimit" : "1000"
    }
}
```

Will anyone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issues - worked perfectly for me. Windows 7 VS2013.

Comment: what should i do now ? is it related to any updates ? which i need to instal on my other machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've run your JSON through 3 different online validators

1. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
2. http://jsonlint.com/
3. http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

I did that because a number of other Stack Overflow questions that related to this error message found slight errors in the parser format and this was causing the error to occur. Such as:

1. [Invalid object error when sending json values with apostrophe to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393321/invalid-object-error-when-sending-json-values-with-apostrophe-to-webservice)
2. [JSON "Invalid object passed in, member name expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423879/json-invalid-object-passed-in-member-name-expected)
3. [Parse Google JSON response in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753326/parse-google-json-response-in-vb-net)

I also processed your input with:

```
dictJson = objScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(line);
```

But found no change, as I said in my comment I cannot reproduce the issue.

If it's only happening on the one machine it must be environmental. Maybe there's a .NET patch that can be applied. For example this patch fixed a very similar looking error in the **JavaScriptSerializer**

> http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775981/kb2656351-javascriptserializer-deserialize-error-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object

I think your best bet is to be sure that the failing machine is up to date with all .NET patches and service packs.

**Update**

Here are some details about how to get access to the patch referenced above. The link above references the following KB - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828843. In that it states that it is available only upon making a request to MS. However a latter update to that KB also references the following link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2889629/en-us.

And on that link it states that this patch is available in the following OS service packs:

> Hotfix rollup 2889629 is available for the .NET Framework 4 on Windows
>   Server 2003 SP2, Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1,
>   Windows Server 2008 SP2, and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2

Comment: Thanks Peter R for your reply. Even i thought its was related to windows update. Thanks again for taking out your time. I gone to that page to download that software but the link is not available any idea where i can get that software to download

Comment: I am still not able to solve this error ? what should i do to get this update manually ? I can't auto update production server ryt ?

Comment: Well I installed .Net Framework 4.5 and it resolved my issue. So the current status of the issue is resolved.

Comment: I didn't notice your message until just now. I'm glad that it's now resolved. I will update the article with details on how to download this patch.

Comment: My problem was also fixed by installing .Net 4.5. Thanks!